# Nav list-style appearing in a different position on chrome

Tags: css, menu

I am working on a site, in which on the main menu (top navbar), I have used `list-style` to separate each menu item. In Firefox is show fine and the small circles are inbetween each menu item as they should be. However on Chrome, they seem to be behind the menu item itself. I'm not sure whether it's something to do with my styling or whether it could possibly be a Chrome bug.

Link to the site:

http://cocobrownboutique.co.uk/site

I'm not going to post all the CSS as it's a Joomla template and thus will be too long, however I will post the my additional CSS:

```
#menubar {
    height: 25px;
}
.menu, .menu ul {
    list-style: circle outside none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.menu-dropdown li.level1 {
        height: 18px;
        padding: 0 32px 0 15px;
}
.menu-dropdown a.level1 > span, .menu-dropdown span.level1 > span {
    line-height: 25px;
}
.menu-dropdown li.level2 {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

If a link to the main menu.css file is required I will of course provide it. I pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated as for the life of me cannot understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried with "firebug" on chrome.

Add float:left; on you're menu-dropdown li :

```
.menu-dropdown li{
position:relative;
float:left;
}
```

And delete this :

```
.menu-dropdown, .menu-dropdown .level1, .menu-dropdown .level1 > span{
float:left; <-- delete this
}
```